# Std Deviation of a point estimate which is the sum of two normally and independently distributed random variables

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, parameter-estimation

The problem States:

Given $\bar x= 41$ and $\bar y= 40.7$.

$σ_x= 0.1$  and  $σ_y= 0.19$

$X \sim N[\mu_X; \sigma^2]; Y \sim N[\mu_Y ; \sigma^2]$; with $\mu_X > 0,\; \mu_Y > 0, \sigma > 0$  and $\theta = µ_X - µ_Y$ .

The two samples are independently distributed and have $n_X = n_Y = 18$.
Now it asks me to find the point estimate for $\theta$ and its standard deviation.

The point estimate is simply $\hat{θ} =  \bar x − \bar y = 41 − 40.7 = 0.3$

Now I have no idea how to find the standard deviation..can't find any similar example on my book or on google.
The solution I'm given is: Standard deviation = $0.05$

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiOz4.png

Comment: How have you calculated the point estimate ?

Comment: I got lost in the formatting and forgot to specify some important data in my question, it should be clearer now, sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: a google search "variance difference of sample means" gives the very first hit https://www.kean.edu/~fosborne/bstat/05b2means.html